# Connection between Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f : [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb R$ be a sufficiently smooth function. I am considering the Fourier series of $f$, i.e. the coefficients

$$c_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} f(x) dx.$$

I was wondering if there was a connection between the $c_n$ and the Fourier coefficients of the function $x \mapsto x f(x)$, i.e.

$$d_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} x f(x) dx.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the integral by over $[-\pi, \pi]$ (or the kernel function by $\exp(i\pi n\cdot)$?

Answer (score 3):

In general if
$$I(k) := \int_{a}^b e^{-ikx} f(x)dx$$
Then
$$J(k) := \int_{a}^b e^{-ikx} xf(x)dx=i\frac{d}{dk} I(k)$$
In your case then
$$d_n = i\frac{dc_n}{dn}$$
where differentiation is done formally (Formally means you are treating $n$ as a differentiable function instead of an integer).